# Solving nonlinear system with fsolve with multiple inputs in matlab

Tags: matlab, solver

I am trying to solve a system of six nonlinear equations using fsolve (see below). There are additional parameters in my equations that I would like to be able to input into the system or change the functionality without having to go into my function and manually editing them each time.

They are `F`, `rho`, and `A`. Right now I have set them all to 1, and I am able to get a solution so at least the script is running correctly.

```
function f = pressXmanifold(x)
    F = [1,1,1];
    rho = 1;
    A = 1;
    f(1) = x(1)-x(3) - ...
        1/2*rho*(x(4)/F(1))^2*...
        A*(x(4)/x(6)*F(3)/F(1))^(-2)*...
        (1+(F(3)/F(1))^2+3*(F(3)/F(1))^2*((x(4)/x(6))^2-(x(4)/x(6))));
    f(2) = x(2)-x(3) - ...
        1/2*rho*(x(5)/F(2))^2*...
        A*(x(5)/x(6)*F(3)/F(2))^(-2)*...
        (1+(F(3)/F(2))^2+3*(F(3)/F(2))^2*((x(5)/x(6))^2-(x(5)/x(6))));
    f(3) = x(1) - x(3);
    f(4) = x(2) - x(3);
    f(5) = x(4) - x(5);
    f(6) = x(4)+x(5) - x(6);
end
```

For `F` I would want to be able to input any 1 x 3 array into my     function. 
For `rho` I would want to input a value as well. 
For `A`, it would have to change with the iterations based on the following criteria (given as an if statement).

```
if F(3)/F(1) <= 0.35 && x(3)/x(2) <= 1
    A = 1;
elseif F(3)/F(1) > 0.35 && x(3)/x(2) <= 0.4
    A = 0.9*(1-x(3)/x(2));
elseif F(3)/F(1) > 0.35 && x(3)/x(2) > 0.4
    A = 0.55;
end
```

For now I've only tried dealing with the first two parameters. `f = pressXmanifold(x,F,rho)` and removing the first two lines in my function.
But when I try to follow the instructions on the MathWorks site

```
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','none','PlotFcn',@optimplotfirstorderopt);
fun = @pressXmanifold;
x0 = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
x = fsolve(fun,x0,F,rho,options)
```

Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
Error in createOptionFeedback (line 33)
            options.(stopTestOptions{k}) = [];
Error in prepareOptionsForSolver (line 57)
    optionFeedback = createOptionFeedback(options);
Error in fsolve (line 157)
[options, optionFeedback] = prepareOptionsForSolver(options, 'fsolve');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Rewrite pressXmanifold including F and rho as input

```
function f = pressXmanifold(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, F, rho)
   if F(3)/F(1) <= 0.35 && x3/x2 <= 1
        A = 1;
    elseif F(3)/F(1) > 0.35 && x3/x2 <= 0.4
        A = 0.9*(1-x3/x2);
    elseif F(3)/F(1) > 0.35 && x3/x2 > 0.4
        A = 0.55;
    end
    f(1) = x1-x3 - ...
        1/2*rho*(x4/F(1))^2*...
        A*(x4/x6*F(3)/F(1))^(-2)*...
        (1+(F(3)/F(1))^2+3*(F(3)/F(1))^2*((x4/x6)^2-(x4/x6)));
    f(2) = x2-x3 - ...
        1/2*rho*(x5/F(2))^2*...
        A*(x5/x6*F(3)/F(2))^(-2)*...
        (1+(F(3)/F(2))^2+3*(F(3)/F(2))^2*((x5/x6)^2-(x5/x6)));
    f(3) = x1 - x3;
    f(4) = x2 - x3;
    f(5) = x4 - x5;
    f(6) = x4+x5 - x6;
end
```

## Then define F and rho

```
rho = 1;
F =[1,1,1];
fun = @(x)pressXmanifold(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5), x(6), F, rho);
```

## Finally

```
options = optimoptions('fsolve','Display','none','PlotFcn',...
    @optimplotfirstorderopt);
x0 = [1,1,1,1,1,1];
x = fsolve(fun,x0,options)
```

Comment: I just noticed, there is an error in your answer but the method seems to be correct. `F` and `rho` should not be changing on each iteration.